How to add labels on relative KDE plots?
I'm trying to plot the KDEs of two datasets using seaborn.kdeplot. I want to add separate labels for each dataset, but I'm having trouble getting the labels to work correctly. Here's my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
data2 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 500)

# Plot the KDEs with weights
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

sns.kdeplot([data1, data2], label=['Data 1', 'Data 2'], fill=True, bw_adjust=1)

plt.title('Relative density plots')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


However, this doesn't give me the correct labels. Both datasets are plotted, but the labels are not assigned properly.
Given a list of multiple arrays, I want to add a list of corresponding labels, but this does not seem to work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

The following code seems to do it, using matplotlib.patches,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
data2 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 500)

# Plot the KDEs with weights
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

sns.kdeplot([data1, data2], fill=True, bw_adjust=1)

labels = ['Data 1', 'Data 2']
handles = [mpatches.Patch(facecolor=color, label=label, alpha=0.5) for color, label in zip(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'], labels)]

plt.title('Relative density plots')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()


